# Removing LinkedList elements using startsWith method in java

Tags: java, collections

I am trying to remove list elements which is starting by r and g

one condition is working fine to remove elememts which starting from r but next one not working in if loop help me where i made mistake. Thank you..!!

my code is

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.LinkedList;

public class EasyRemovingList {
    void removeList(){
    String[] inpArray={"red","green","blue","ivory"};
    LinkedList<String> upList = new LinkedList<String>(Arrays.asList(inpArray));
    System.out.println("Actual "+upList+" "+upList.size());
    //System.out.println(upList.get(3));
    for(int i = 0;i<upList.size();i++){
        //System.out.println(upList.get(i));    
    if(upList.get(i).startsWith("r")||upList.get(i).startsWith("g")){
        upList.remove(i);
        System.out.println("Updated "+upList);
    }
    }
    //System.out.println(upList);
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        EasyRemovingList er = new EasyRemovingList();
        er.removeList();

    }

}
```

output is

```
Actual [red, green, blue, ivory] 4
Updated [green, blue, ivory]
```

Expected output is

```
Actual [red, green, blue, ivory] 4
Updated [blue, ivory]
```

Comment: When you remove an element you'll be skipping the next one since every element shifts over. Start the end of the `LinkedList` and go backward to avoid this

Comment: Hi GB bro i did not get you once it is comes into for loop i have provided the if condition to remove right and inside i am using remove comment to update the list again, where i am doing wrong can you please be more specific thank you

Comment: You shouldn't need a `loop` to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you remove an element all the other elements will shift over, and you will skip the next element. To avoid this simply start at one minus the length of the `LinkedList` and loop until `i` is equal to zero:

```
for(int i = upList.size()-1;i>=0;i--){    
    if(upList.get(i).startsWith("r")||upList.get(i).startsWith("g")){
        upList.remove(i);        
    }
}
System.out.println("Updated "+upList);
}
```

**Output:**

```
Actual [red, green, blue, ivory] 4
Updated [blue, ivory]
```

Comment: Hi GB bro thanks a lot it is working fine and implemented as per your way but i wonder initially i value should be size -1  should be 3 right how come it is printing 4 to 0...? as i am beginner i am trying to know better bro. thanks again for your help...!!

Comment: you there bro ...@gblodgett

Comment: @Atom I'm not sure I understand what you are asking. What is printing 4 to zero?

Comment: I got it when the condition uplist.size()-1 checks in for loop it will reduce the size right i just checked out printing what i expected i just confused myself on i value and could understand now @GB never mind . Thanks a ;pt again

Answer (score 2):

Try using `removeIf()`.

```
upList.removeIf(element -> {return element.starts("r") || element.startsWith("g");});
```

> MVCE

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.LinkedList;

/**
 *
 * @author Sedrick
 */
public class JavaApplication4 {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[] inpArray={"red","green","blue","ivory"};
        LinkedList<String> upList = new LinkedList(Arrays.asList(inpArray));
        System.out.println("Actual "+upList+" "+upList.size());

        upList.removeIf(element -> {
            return element.startsWith("r") || element.startsWith("g"); //To change body of generated lambdas, choose Tools | Templates.
        });

        System.out.println("Actual "+upList+" "+upList.size());

    }

}
```

> Results

```
run:
Actual [red, green, blue, ivory] 4
Actual [blue, ivory] 2
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 0 seconds)
```

Comment: wow ..!! amazing you have used new function i guess lamda expression and all i am eagerly waiting to learn and use it... thanks for your time and help bro

Answer (score 2):

You are removing while traversing which is a bad smell in coding.

You can try to use *iterator* to do the removing.

With `iterator`, you use it as

```
while(iter.hasNext()) {
    String s = iter.next();
    if (s. startsWith(“r”) || s. startsWith(“g”)) {
          iter.remove();
    }
}
```

Comment: yes hearen brother, i tried in your way which is pretty simple thanks for assisting me to learn new things

ListIterator<String> iter = upList.listIterator();
 while(iter.hasNext()) {
     String s = iter.next();
     if (s. startsWith("r") || s. startsWith("g")) {
           iter.remove();
     }
 }System.out.println("Updated "+upList);

Answer (score 0):

You can use Java 8 for a simple solution:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.function.Predicate;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class StackOverFlow {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[] inpArray = { "red", "green", "blue", "ivory" };
        LinkedList<String> upList = new LinkedList<String>(Arrays.asList(inpArray));
        System.out.println("Actual " + upList + " " + upList.size());

        Predicate<String> p = e -> e.startsWith("r") || e.startsWith("g");

        // Return a new list
        System.out.println(upList.stream().filter(p.negate()).collect(Collectors.toList()));

        // Updates your existing list
        upList.removeIf(p);
        System.out.println(upList);

    }

}
```

Comment: Hi Adarsh bro thanks for an update i have tried executing your code but below line showing error  


Predicate<String> p = e -> e.startsWith("r") || e.startsWith("g");

it may be because i am using javaSE is 1.7 right ...? my jre is 1.8 though

Comment: @Atom Yes, these predicates, lambdas, and Stream API are available with Java 8 onward.